# Getting 404 error after running serve -l ./build after building react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, serve

I get 404 error when I try to run this command

```sh
serve -l build
```

after building a react app, this is my ./app.js and react-router that is implemented inside the file.

```js
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Components/Header";
import LeafletContainer from "./container/LeafletContainer";
import SignUp from "./Components/SignUp";
import Profile from "./Components/Profile";
import SavedLocations from "./Components/SavedLocations";
import Swiper from "./Components/swiper";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const Slash = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <LeafletContainer />
      <Swiper />
    </>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Slash} />
          <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
          <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
          <Route exact path="/locations" component={SavedLocations} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and also I have defined this line in ./package.json

```json
{
...,
    "homepage": "."
...,
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a blank string as `homepage`? Or removing it altogether? Try `serve build` instead.

Comment: What is `serve -l ./build` expected to do?

Comment: Why are you using the `--listen` flag in the first place?

Comment: @ChrisG I have fixed the issue using this commend ```bash   serve -s build``` thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **-l** flag you should provide a endpoint/ports which should listen. I suppose you should use **-s** flag in your case:

```
serve -s build
```

Or you can add port to your command like this:

```
serve -l 3232 build
```

Then you can find your app on **localhost:3232**